# hrule inside minipage refuses to show up

Tags: minipage, rules

Inside a minipage, `\hrule` doesn't seem to do anything unless there is already some material inside the minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule width\textwidth\relax
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
  %\strut
  \hrule width0.5\textwidth\relax
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

The first hrule of width `\textwidth` is drawn, but the second one is
nowhere to be seen.  However if you add a `\strut` (or anything else) before the rule, then it misteriously appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is drawn but touching your previous rule. If you comment out that, you see it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%\hrule width\textwidth\relax
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
  %\strut
  \hrule width0.5\textwidth\relax
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, it makes all the sense. The strut just pushes the second rule down.

Comment: @ErnestA If you'd used the latex command \rule rather than the primitive \hrule you would not have this problem

Comment: Not really over, but *just below*.

Comment: @egreg yes of course, posted an image

Answer (score 5):

The `minipage` is doing nothing strange: at the end of the road, it is essentially transformed into

```
\vbox{\hrule width0.5\textwidth\relax}
```

and TeX assigns to it the same height as the rule, that is, 0.4pt.

A peculiar feature of TeX is that it adds no interline glue after `\hrule`, so no vertical space is added between the first rule and the following paragraph.

Indeed, the same result is obtained by saying

```
\hrule width\textwidth\relax
\hrule width0.5\textwidth\relax
```

The effect is more visible by using thicker rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\hrule width 2cm height 2pt\relax
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
  \hrule width 1cm height 2pt\relax
\end{minipage}

\medskip

\hrule width 2cm height 2pt\relax
\hrule width 1cm height 2pt\relax

\end{document}
```

[image]

Add some vertical space after the rule, such as `\medskip`.

Comment: IIUC `\hrulewidth0.5` should be `\hrule width0.5`, that space matters, right?

Comment: @Blaisorblade Yes, of course you’re right

Comment: @jfbu Until you typeset something, the box width is zero.